# Почему в devtools стили из файлов показываются не их путь в файле со строкой нахождения, а все обёрнуты тэгом style?

Tags: google-chrome, браузер, google-chrome-devtools

Использую браузер Хром, при просмотре стилей в DevTools я всегда раньше видел какой стиль в каком файле находится, в конкретной строчке. Но, сегодня, только мой сайт, при просмотре стилей, все стили без адреса, обернуты тэгом style:

[image]

В чем может быть проблема?

Как вернуть к такому формату:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

???

Comment: Потому что webpack.

Comment: @Qwertiy Конкретнее, пожалуйста, я не пойму, что это значит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем такое оказалось из-за скрипта prefixfree.min.js. Этот кусок говна ставит префиксы под разные браузеры в css. Но! Кроме этого этот же скрипт переименовал все ссылки на файлы css. Возможно кому-то данный скрипт будет полезен. Я его вычеркнул и всё заработало.